# why isnt the inode id of dotdot didnt have the updated inode id?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I have a function that backtracks from the child directory to the root by getting the inode id of the parent from the ".." dentry of the child. The main purpose of this backtracking is to identify the relative path name of the path entered by the user.

I know the child inode id to do the above backtracking but I have got a problem when I do so. After evacuation the child and the parent directories have different inode numbers so when backtraced with "..", dotdot gave the inode id of the previous number and not the inode number after the evacuation.

Why isn't the inode id of dotdot the same as the updated inode id?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to make a comment, so I must do answer your question even if I cannot fully understand what do you mean with

> the updated inode id

OK, to get the path from the root directory to a directory where you are, we go in the reverse direction.  You have first to get the inode number of the directory you are on (you get it from the `.` entry), then get to the parent directory through the `..` entry and then search in the parent directory looking for a directory that has the same inode number you have got at the beginning.  This is the name of this directory entry in the parent directory.  This way you'll get how this directory `.` is called on the parent directory... repeating this iteration you'll get you granparent directory name... and so on, until.... what?

Ok, the root directory has a `..` entry that points to itself (as `.` does) and you have to compare the inode number you got last time with the one you have got in this iteration, and stop if they are the same inode number.  Once this special directory has ben reached, you have a list of names you have to reverse, put slashes / between them and you'll have the path to the actual directory.

If you are not in the root filesystem the kernel makes the magic you need to get to the parent directory (it follows the `..` entry through the mount points ignoring that the `..` entry points to itself) and you'll get the path to the root directory correctly, so you can follow this methot until you get `.` and `..` pointing to the same inode.

I expect this fully answers you question.